# difference between "shave" and "get a shave"

Tags: word-usage

What's the difference between: ***I get a shave*** and ***I shave***?

Is *get a shave* causative verb?

If a person shaves his beard on his own, how to describe the same?

Answer (score 2):

"get" is being used in its normal meaning of "acquire". If you "get a shave" you are getting the shave *from someone else*. It suggests that you went to the barber, and he shaved you.

If you shave your own beard, then the simple verb "shave" is correct.

> I woke up, showered, shaved, and ate breakfast before 7:00.
>
> Every Monday I get a shave at the Turkish barber's.

You may occasionally hear "get shaved".  This can be the "get passive"  Such as "I got shaved by the barber" or it can be used to indicate that you the shave was completed: "I woke up and got shaved.